# Почему wireshark создает огромное количество запросов Who has?

Tags: сеть, администрирование, трафик, wireshark, arp

Постоянно в wireshark создается куча ARP запросов. Источник ZyxelCom (это походу мой роутер), Destination - Broadcast (это походу широковещательный). И пошли запросы Who has 192.168.1.1 Tell 192.168.1.1 Who has 192.168.1.2 Tell 192.168.1.1 ... и так до Who has 192.168.1.254 и потом по новой. Почему так? Такое происходит даже если отключить от интернета, только внутри локальной сети

Comment: Почему создает запросы роутер, а пишете вы, что создает их Wireshark? :-)

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов Не знаю кто именно их создает, но в источнике указан Источник ZyxelCom - это скорее всего мой роутер

Comment: А пишете вы, что создает их Wireshark. Но он - не роутер :-)

Comment: ну так работает ARP протокол, ему чтобы доставить сообщение надо узнать из широковещательной рассылки кому он предназначен.

Comment: @tcpack4 И он круглосуточно делает такую рассылку? Зачем ему это делать 10000 раз в сутки?  Это нормально? Причем он запрашивает все внутренние IP-адреса, на которых даже ничего нет.

Comment: Опрашивает только при запросе к тому хосту. После добавляет в кеш на определенно время и затем стучится напрямую по мак адресу. Если запрашиваются хосты, на которых ничего нет, значит что-то на них хочет послать. В ваершарке это можно посмотреть - вместе с ARP к ним идет другой запрос по другому протоколу.

Comment: @tcpack4 Так я же говорю, что он запрашивает вообще всегда, и на все возможные IP с 1-го по 255, затем снова и так круглые сутки. Хотя по сути заняты всего 4-5 IP в локальной сети

Comment: если отправляются на все подряд адреса, то скорее всего это работает сканер сети.

Comment: @tcpack4 что за сканер?

Comment: Программа для сканирования открытых портов, например nmap. Где можно в заданном диапазоне проверять у каждого хоста наличие открытых портов, обычно из стандартных. Может применятся для поиска уязвимых служб. Определите какой хост посылает запрос, а затем какой процесс использует порт отправителя.